# How to find documents and NOT convert all _ids to String in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find, objectid

Whenever you use collenction.find({}) all fields that contain ids like {"$oid": "64e6fb236049651f4cebdc1"}, automatically get converted to String "64e6fb236049651f4cebdc1".

Is it possible to make MongoDB keep all ids in their object form when finding documents? (in node.js)

I am aware that you can convert individual ids back to an object using MongoDB.ObjectID(string) but that's not what I need because in my case all objects have different structure and have multiple fields containing ids.

I tried Googling it but all I got was answers to similar sounding but different questions.
I tried reading the docs for mongodb find and findOptions [text](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0//interfaces/findoptions.html) but it seems like there isn't anything that can help

Comment: What makes you believe the field values are getting converted from ObjectIds to strings? This doesn't sound like something that a driver or library would typically do. Notably sometimes it may _look_ like this when logging to the console since that requires a text-based representation of the document/value

Comment: @user20042973 This is the default behavior of [official mongodb package for nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) It just works this way.

Comment: Can you substantiate that claim more than pointing to the page for the npm package (which doesn't mention `ObjectId`s)? I just ran a quick test with driver version `5.8.1` using the sample "_Find All Documents_" code on that page with a single document in the collection and the logged output was `Found documents => [  { _id: new ObjectId("64e92fa749ae62379ab333e1"), str: 'some string' }]`. Looks to me like the ObjectId retained its original type when retrieved (and printed) by the driver in the client app.